# load() not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello Friends check my code http://jsfiddle.net/sUaky/2/  i want to load a web page in a div using the `load()` function but code is not working plz help me out

Thank in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [Load a external URL into a div using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453844/load-a-external-url-into-a-div-using-jquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is you id??
that you are trying to click like??

```
$('#tab-1').click();
```

your click event not happening because there is no id you are getting.

According to your fiddle, first you have to get the `href` attributes value, then your match your click event with the value.

**UPDATE**

try with this example,,

```
$('#tabs ul li a').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        if( id == '#tab-1' ){
            alert(id);

            // Don't use cross domain here
            $('#youtube_tab').load('index.html');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: #tab-1 is apply on <ul> first <li> 


      <li><a href="#tab-1">Videos of the day</a></li>

Comment: @user1289808 you are right, but i am talking about the click event. your `#tab-1` is the `href` value not your id, that you call in click event. To do this first you should have to get the `href` value, then the click event.

Comment: If you only want to perform some action for an anchor with a specific `href` value, use the attribute selector: `$('#tabs a[href="#tab-1"]').click(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Cross Domain wont work. You can only load pages the same domain where the page is loaded.

Read more here :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @user1289808: There is nothing to try out (are you sure you understood the problem?), it simply is not possible. You have to use a proxy if you want to access external content via Ajax.

Comment: i tried to load page with same domain . nbut its also not working

http://jsfiddle.net/sUaky/6/

Comment: alert is also not working when i use it in the place of load()

check http://jsfiddle.net/sUaky/7/

Comment: @user1289808: It does not work, because (a) jsfiddle does not have a `click.html` page, so you cannot load it and (b) you have no element with ID `tab-1`, so you cannot bind an event handler to it. I suggest you read up again on the basics of jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials and related topics (such as DOM). This site is not the place to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

Jogesh is right.  But to solve, just give your anchors an id, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StefanCoetzee/sUaky/8/).

Then choose a local page that you are allowed to load, for the url.